# Python's request() returning response 400 when trying to get file from API

Tags: python, python-requests

This is my first time messing with APIs. I wrote some code to get data from USASpending's API using a 'GET' call and it works. I'm now trying to get data from another endpoint that only has 'post' capability. The code below returns the '400' response. I'm not sure what I need to change to get the output to be produced. I don't know if it matters but this endpoint produces a zip file.

```
import requests

payload = {"award_levels":["prime_awards"],"filters":{"award_types":["contracts","direct_payments","grants","idvs","loans","other_financial_assistance"],"agency":"United States Mint","date_type":"action_date","date_range":{"start_date":"2019-01-01","end_date":"2019-01-31"}},"columns":[],"file_format":"csv"}

response = requests.post('https://api.usaspending.gov/api/v2/bulk_download/awards/', params = payload).json()
```

Thanks in advance

Update:

This is what I finally used. I have the date as dynamic so I can automate this pull monthly using task scheduler. If you want to pull a specific date, remove the date variable reference in the header declaration and run.

```
pl_str1 = """{
"filters": {
"prime_award_types": [
"A",
"B",
"C",
"D",
"IDV_A",
"IDV_B",
"IDV_B_A",
"IDV_B_B",
"IDV_B_C",
"IDV_C",
"IDV_D",
"IDV_E",
"02",
"03",
"04",
"05",
"10",
"06",
"07",
"08",
"09",
"11"],
"agency": 54,
"date_type": "action_date","""
# Inserting date_range variable into API call
pl_str2 =  '"date_range": {"start_date":'  + date_3Months_prior +', "end_date":' + date_today + '}'
pl_str3 = """},
"columns": [],
"file_format": "csv"}"""

desired_payload = pl_str1 + pl_str2 + pl_str3

# $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ REQUESTING DESIRED INFO FROM THE API HERE $$$$$$        
url = 'https://api.usaspending.gov/api/v2/bulk_download/awards/'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=desired_payload)
if resp.status_code == 200:
    print('success')
    print(resp.content)
else:
    print('fail')
    
# API returns a zip file; grabbing that   
# This will turn the API response into a string I can use regex on
test = resp.content.decode('UTF-8')
# Extracting url for zip we want to retrieve
test2 = re.findall(r"file_url\S+\.zip", test)[0]
test3 = re.findall(r"https\S+\.zip", test2)[0]

import zipfile
import io
import time
r = requests.get(test3)
# add sleep in case it takes a while for the API to return stuff; not sure if 
# but just in case
time.sleep(5)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall()
```

Comment: 400 means Bad Request. To know what is wrong with your request we need to know what the API endpoint is expecting.

Comment: you are not some required parameters. see [here](https://github.com/fedspendingtransparency/usaspending-api/blob/master/usaspending_api/api_contracts/contracts/v2/bulk_download/awards.md)

Comment: Yes, I saw that. According to their documentation, the only required  parameter is "filters"

Comment: @wolf7687 did you ever get this working? i'm also getting the 500 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` are the query parameters in the URL.

e.g

`www.stackoverflow.com?parameter=test`

This can be expressed as

```
payload = {
     "parameter": "test"
}
```

POST request has a `body`, This is the same data that would've been sent if you were posting from a form, You're sending a `body`, You have some parameters in requests module function `.post` that deal with the body, You can either use `data=payload` or `json=payload`, [See](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) the official documentation on this.

Comment: Well that's a start. Now I'm getting a 500 response instead of 400. I guess that's something I need to bring-up with the site administrators?

Comment: This is a bug or an error in their server. No your part is done well, Use another API, [see](https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis)

Answer (score 0):

When you run this url (https://api.usaspending.gov/api/v2/bulk_download/awards/) in browser and fill form with your request. You will get respons like this 
{
    "detail": "Missing one or more required body parameters: prime_award_types or sub_award_types"
}

Add fliters, data_range, data_type , agency,prime_award_types
Your request should be like this:

```
{
"filters": {
    "date_range": {
        "start_date": "2019-01-01",
        "end_date": "2019-12-31"
    },
    "date_type": "action_date",
    "agency": 50,
    "prime_award_types": [
        "02",
        "03",
        "04",
        "05",
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D"
    ],
    "award_levels": [
        "prime_awards"
    ],
    "filters": {
        "award_types": [
            "contracts",
            "direct_payments",
            "grants",
            "idvs",
            "loans",
            "other_financial_assistance"
        ],
        "agency": "United States Mint",
        "date_type": "action_date",
        "date_range": {
            "start_date": "2019-01-01",
            "end_date": "2019-01-31"
        }
    },
    "columns": [],
    "file_format": "csv"
}
```

}

Comment: Pawel, why does your code work when I plug it into the URL but not when I run request via python?

Answer (score 0):

Get form data in function and send it an other function with request.

```
import requests
from flask import Flask, return , request, 

@videos.route("/ajaxprocess", methods=["GET","POST"])
def ajaxprocess():
    if request.method =="POST":

       text = request.form.get('text_text')
        font = request.form.get('font_text')
        color = request.form.get('color_text')
        start_text = request.form.get('start_text')
        end_text = request.form.get('end_text')
        video_id = request.form.get('vid')
        all_data = {'status':'OK','text':text,'font':font,'color':color,'start_text':start_text,'end_text':end_text,'vid':video_id}
        r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/videos/test_text",json=all_data)
        print(r)
        return redirect(url_for("videos.show_videos"))
        

@videos.route("/test_text", methods = ['POST'])

def test_text():
   
    data = request.get_json("")
    print(data)

    return "success!"
```